# std::string::c_str() overwrittes the previous one returned by a function

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, stack, stdstring

I could not understand that how can be the pointers same when the text size is equal. It seems like firstStringObj::c_str() overwrittes the previous one's pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

std::string getConstCharAndModifyItWithANewString( const char* constchar )
{
    std::string stringAtStack( constchar );
    stringAtStack += "::isModified";
    return stringAtStack;
}

int main()
{
    const char* firstConstCharPointer = getConstCharAndModifyItWithANewString("Hi!").c_str();
    std::string firstStringObj = "Hi+";

    printf(" firstConstCharPointer(%s)(%p)\nfirstStringObj(%s)(%p)\n\n", firstConstCharPointer,firstConstCharPointer, firstStringObj.c_str(),     firstStringObj.c_str()  );
}
```

OUTPUT:
firstConstCharPointer(Hi+)(0x4593eb8)
firstStringObj(Hi+)(0x4593eb8)

Comment: Looks like a compiler optimization problem. Does not happen on gcc 4.9.2

Comment: You're observing undefined behaviour, so you can't blame optimizations. Also: read the docs of `.c_str()`

Comment: Does not happen on the long sized strings.

Comment: Yes, it is not an optimisation problem. Because, codechef passes but cpp.sh fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns a **temporary** `std::string` object.  After the `firstConstCharPointer` variable is assigned and the expression is complete, that temporary object gets destroyed, freeing its allocated memory block and leaving the variable pointing at freed memory.  This is known as a **dangling pointer**.

`firstStringObj` then allocates a new memory block, which *happens* to be reusing the same memory block that the temp `std::string` had previously allocated and freed.  So the dangling pointer *happens* to now be pointing at valid memory again.  That is why your `printf()` statement is able to display the same memory address and content for both strings.

But this is **undefined behavior**.  The memory block that gets allocated each time is completely up to the string's `Allocator` to decide.  The second `std::string` could just as easily have allocated a completely different memory block, and then the code would be more likely to crash, or at least print garbage, when it tries to dereference the dangling pointer that is still pointing at invalid memory.

In order for your code to work, you need to change `firstConstCharPointer` to a `std::string` object so the temp `std::string` gets copied properly, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

std::string getConstCharAndModifyItWithANewString( const char* constchar )
{
    std::string stringAtStack( constchar );
    stringAtStack += "::isModified";
    return stringAtStack;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string firstConstStringObj = getConstCharAndModifyItWithANewString("Hi!");
    std::string secondStringObj = "Hi!";

    std::printf(" firstConstStringObj(%s)(%p)\nsecondStringObj(%s)(%p)\n\n", firstConstStringObj.c_str(), firstConstStringObj.c_str(), secondStringObj.c_str(), secondStringObj.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The pointers are the same on your platform because `firstConstCharPointer` is a dangling pointer, it points to deallocated memory.

That's because the `std::string` returned by `getConstCharAndModifyItWithANewString` is destroyed after assignment expression `const char* firstConstCharPointer = ...;`.

So when you create a new `std::string` object, the compile choose to use the same memory location as the previous `std::string` object, and so the pointers are the same.

On my platform for example the pointers are the same, and they're not in [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ntnxTa).

Answer (score 4):

You have classic undefined behaviour. `printf` tries to derefenrece `firstConstCharPointer` because of `%s`. `firstConstCharPointer` points to data that has been destroyed because the `std::string` associated with this pointer's lifetime stops after the assignment:

```
const char* firstConstCharPointer = getConstCharAndModifyItWithANewString("Hi!").c_str();
// temporary std::string returned from getConstCharAndModifyItWithANewString destroyed, pointer becomes dangling.
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [documentation:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

> The pointer obtained from c_str() may be invalidated by:
>
> - Passing a non-const reference to the string to any standard library function, or
> - Calling non-const member functions on the string, excluding operator[], at(), front(), back(), begin(), rbegin(), end() and rend().

So you are using invalid pointer, as destructor is a non-const member function and is not listed above.